# Is there any reason to upgrade to a newer router than a WRT45G?

Tags: wireless-networking, hardware-rec

I've always used my Linksys WRT45G as my wireless router since I bought it almost 6ish years ago. I love it because of it's hackability, but I'm about to upgrade my service to 20 Mbps down 5 up, and I wonder if my old wireless router will be the new bottleneck?

Comment: That old router is limited to  54 Mbps over wireless, but if you upgrade to a wireless N router of other faster wireless technology, you will have to upgrade the wireless adapters in your PC's to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wont be a bottleneck.  All the wired ports and the wireless are still faster than your 20 Mbps downstream connection.